# Не удается реализовать функцию "пауза" и "продолжить" для QProcess в C++ Qt в среде Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

Не удается реализовать функцию "пауза" и "продолжить" для QProcess в C++ Qt в среде Windows (в Linux данный метод работает):

```
#include <signal.h>

kill(pid_t(process_1->processId()), SIGSTOP); // pause

kill(pid_t(process_1->processId()), SIGCONT); // resume
```

Как реализовать данные опции для Windows?

Comment: вам понадобится перебрать потоки процесса и вызвать для каждого SuspendThread.

Comment: нуда... нормального способа похоже нет... ещё в добавление к `SuspendThread`/`ResumeThread` есть недокументированные `_NtSuspendProcess()`/`_NtResumeProcess()`, как пишут [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100480/how-to-pause-resume-any-external-process-under-windows#answer-61371356).

Answer (score 0):

Получилось это сделать следующим способом:

```
QProcess *process_1 = new QProcess(this);
.
.
.
PROCESS_INFORMATION *pi = process_1->pid();

SuspendThread(pi->hThread);
.
.
.
ResumeThread(pi->hThread);
```